# How to list all commits incorrectly merged to release branch in git?

Tags: git, gitlab

we're using a trunk based model to develop a 2 phased project where `master` has the latest code and `release/phase1` has the code for the first release. Both of said branches are protected and requires merge request to push code. We're using Gitlab CE 11.0.3.

Recently we have found some master code has been merged to the `release/phase1`. This is because one of the developer has incorrectly branched from the `master` for a phase1 fixing. It was merged 3 weeks ago and now the merge requested cannot be reverted automatically due to conflict with code changes afterward. Also, there may be other incorrect merge request.

Now that you guys know how fxxked up is the situation,

1. I would like to revert all incorrect commits. Is it possible to list all commits branched from master?

I have tried with the following

```
#Try to get all "Merge branch 'xxxx' into 'master'" commit
git log release/phase1.. --pretty=oneline | grep master
```

But it doesn't list the incorrect commit I have in mind for some reasons. Also even if it does it won't be very helpful as the actual master code change commits are not listed.

2. Is there better way besides reverting commit by commit?

Thanks for reading.

Edit 20181016-2:
Simplified branch graph:
[image]

So feature/fix_for_phase1 should be branched from release/phase1 but it didn't. Therefore some unwanted master code was included when merge back to release/phase1. I believe there were other feature/fix_phase1_xxx is doing the same. How can I find and revert these?

Comment: Can you share what the git tree looks like?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Add as edited. it is pretty messy though

Comment: Remember a branch is just a pointer to a commit. You can move these around freely. You can also copy commits too.

Comment: It is pretty messy, would you be able to write a simplified version in text as it stands, and show what you think you'd want?

Comment: @evolutionxbox updated again. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to remove all commits from `feature/fix_for_phase1` from `release/phase1`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes. Technically some commits should be included but I can do that separately. I just want to list out all such commits before I can handle those.

Comment: In my mind, to remove the merge of the feature into release, I would rebase release onto the commit before the merge. This wouldn’t need me to list all the commits in feature.